# Symfony2 - FOS UserBundle - Original request redirection

Tags: authentication, redirect, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOS UserBundle and I have defined a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` to show a different home page depending on the roles, but I think it should be called only if the user originally requested the login page, shouldn't it ?

On login success I'd like to be redirected to the original request.

As described in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form), it seems to be the default behavior, but in my case, it still uses my authentication handler.

Can someone help me to redirect the user to his original request ?

---

For the record, here is how I registered my authentication success handler service:

```
services:
    security.success_handler:
        class:  Glide\SecurityBundle\[...]\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
        public: false
        arguments: ['@router', '@security.context']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the default behavior is to redirect the user to the page they originally requested. However, since you are overriding the default authentication handler, you need to handle redirecting them to that page yourself.

I recommend you look at [symfonys authentication handler](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.2/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler.php) and mimic its process for figuring out the users original request.

Comment: You mean I have to re-implement the whole service ? Isn't there a way to inherit some jobs ? Like default paths gathering.

Comment: I haven't actually done what your trying to accomplish before, but I assume you can extend the class and then use some of its methods - such as determineTargetUrl()

Comment: Ok I'll try that. I'm trying to get this `providerKey` (in order to fetch the original request) but I don't know where it is set.